# Stylesheets not loading on certain pages

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

i am using master pages in my application and all custom styling and bootstrap files are included there and its working fine but when i use wildcard for example localhost/final/User/id all bootstrap and custom styling links could not work, all files are in public folder

```
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/portal-style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/portal-stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

this is screen shot for my view with wildcard

[image]

this is link for all files that is not working when i use any wildcard

[image]

Comment: you could also just use a root relative path like `/css/bootstrap.css`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally You can use `asset()` or `secure_asset()` for HTTPS, both will work when your assets, like css or js files are in `public` folder.
Or if you are not using public folder. Than `url()` will be there for you.

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

OR

```
<link href="{{ url('public/css/bootstrap.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`asset()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#method-asset) helper to build links to CSS:

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

It'll work for you if you're keeping css files in `public/css` directory.

Answer (score 2):

The reason this is happening is because of the way you have coded the path to the css file which is relative to the page you are viewing.

So when you view: `localhost/final/user/id` the browser is going to look for the css file here: `localhost/final/user/css/bootstrap.css`

Laravel has some helper methods to remove the pain of setting up your asset files (css, images, etc).

If you are using blade, you can use the [`asset()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-asset) method like this:

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ asset('css/font-awesome.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ asset('css/portal-style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ asset('css/portal-stylesheet.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```